# How to get the id of a clicked table header item with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Question**

When I click the table header row, I would like a generic function to get the `id` of the clicked `<th>` element, so I don't have to create a separate function for each header item.

I'm using jQuery, and have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="title">
    <table class="policies sortable">
        <thead id="h-th">
        <tr id="h-tr">
            <th width="3%" id="h-client">Client</th>
            <th width="7%" id="h-company-code">Company Code</th>
            <th width="9%" id="h-unique-reference">Unique Reference</th>
            <th width="8%" id="h-doc-date">Document Date</th>
            <th width="8%" id="h-post-date">Posting Date</th>
            <th width="7%" id="h-doc-type">Document Type</th>
            <th width="5%" id="h-trip-id">Trip Id</th>
            <th width="7%" id="h-ticket-no">Ticket Number</th>
            <th width="6%" id="h-calc-tax">Calculate Tax</th>
            <th width="15%" id="h-passenger-name">Passenger Name</th>
            <th width="4%" id="h-error">Valid</th>
            <th width="4%" id="h-processed">Processed</th>
            <th width="4%" id="h-payment">Payment</th>
            <th width="11%" id="h-updated">Updated</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
        $("#h-tr").click(function(item) {
            console.log(item);
            // get the id of the clicked <th>
        });
```

Comment: Attach the click handler to the `th` cells, not the `tr`, then use `this.id`

Comment: Or use event delegation... `$("#h-tr").on("click", "th[id]", function() { console.log(this.id) })`

Comment: You can retrieve it by using `item.target.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you include the th to the selector then you can access the id using $(this)

```
 $("#h-tr th").click(function(item) {
     console.log($(this).prop('id'));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

### With plain Vanilla JS

> You can call `querySelectorAll()` on all `th` elements and use a loop
> to iterate and `console.log()` attributes once the **EventListener** is
> triggered by the element clicked.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {              
    console.log(element.getAttribute('id'))
  })
})
```

```css
th{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<div id="title">
    <table class="policies sortable">
        <thead id="h-th">
        <tr id="h-tr">
            <th width="3%" id="h-client">Client</th>
            <th width="7%" id="h-company-code">Company Code</th>
            <th width="9%" id="h-unique-reference">Unique Reference</th>
            <th width="8%" id="h-doc-date">Document Date</th>
            <th width="8%" id="h-post-date">Posting Date</th>
            <th width="7%" id="h-doc-type">Document Type</th>
            <th width="5%" id="h-trip-id">Trip Id</th>
            <th width="7%" id="h-ticket-no">Ticket Number</th>
            <th width="6%" id="h-calc-tax">Calculate Tax</th>
            <th width="15%" id="h-passenger-name">Passenger Name</th>
            <th width="4%" id="h-error">Valid</th>
            <th width="4%" id="h-processed">Processed</th>
            <th width="4%" id="h-payment">Payment</th>
            <th width="11%" id="h-updated">Updated</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```